# AngularJS TypeScript TypeError, Whats Wrong?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following piece of code.

```
public showUserPosts(user: User): void {
    this.userPosts$ = fromPromise(this.$http.get<Post[]>(AppRootController.USER_POSTS_URL.concat(user.id.toString()))).pipe(
      map((res: IHttpResponse<Post[]>) => res.data),
    );
    this.postsLoaded = true;
    this.selectedUser = user;
  }
```

Iam calling it on click with ng-click.

```
<li ng-repeat="u in app.users$" ng-click="app.showUserPosts(u)" class="users-wrap-element" ng-class="{ 'users-wrap-element-selected' : app.selectedUser.id === u.id}">
                <p>{{ u.username }}</p>
            </li>
```

This gives me an error "TypeErrror user.id is undefined"

Can sb tell me what am I doing Wrong?

Comment: The error says that the passed argument(user) is undefined. How are you calling `showUserPosts`?

Comment: In template I have ng-click. Then I call that function with u parameter witch is single user in users array. It happens only in browser because the code compiles fine. Error appears only in browser

Comment: Add a `console.log(user)` before `this.userPosts$ ...` to see what object you ve got from the template and post the result. It would be nice if you could edit your answer to include the template related code.